# How can i solve "architecture not supported" when installing flask_mysqldb in venv

Tags: python, pip, clang, mysql-python

i got this error when i run `pip install flask-mysqldb` in my project venv:

```
 In file included from MySQLdb/_mysql.c:29:
    In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.23_1/include/mysql/mysql.h:46:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:81:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/endian.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
    20 errors generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I have python 3.8.2

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a MacOS. Check which `clang` are you using, as it seems that it is the source of your error. If it shows you some error when trying to run the `clang` command directly from your console, try to do a fresh Xcode installation with `xcode-select --install`. By doing so, maybe you can run now the `clang` command without errors, and therefore, install the pip library.

Check this [post](https://mbbroberg.fun/clang-error-in-pip/) for more details.